# UIImage from URL take too much time to appear

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, lazy-loading

I'm trying to loading an image from an URL. The loading works fine but the image take too much time to appear. Sometimes, I need to switch between tab (with my tab bar controller) to see the news images. So, I'm looking for a way to speed up its loading to imageview.

```
        let discoverTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: discoverUrl!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {

            let jsonString: String = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

            if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {

                if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {

                    for item in json["results"].arrayValue {
                        posterURLString = posterBaseURL + item["poster_path"].stringValue
                        discoverPosters.append(posterURLString)
                    }

                    var i = 0
                    while(i < discoverPosters.count)
                    {
                        let posterURL = URL(string: discoverPosters[i])!
                        discoverPostersData.append(try! Data(contentsOf: posterURL))
                        i = i+1
                    }

//I'm setting the new picture from the URL

                    let toDiscoverPoster1 = UIImage(data: discoverPostersData[0])
                    UIView.transition(with: self.discoverPoster1,
                                      duration:1,
                                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                      animations: { self.discoverPoster1.image = toDiscoverPoster1 },
                                      completion: nil)

                    let toDiscoverPoster2 = UIImage(data: discoverPostersData[1])
                    UIView.transition(with: self.discoverPoster2,
                                      duration:1,
                                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                      animations: { self.discoverPoster2.image = toDiscoverPoster2 },
                                      completion: nil)

                    let toDiscoverPoster3 = UIImage(data: discoverPostersData[2])
                    UIView.transition(with: self.discoverPoster3,
                                      duration:1,
                                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                                      animations: { self.discoverPoster3.image = toDiscoverPoster3 },
                                      completion: nil)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS : Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: It's not possible to decide or "fix" how long it takes an image to display. This is based on system performance for a user. The best way to ensure images load quickly is to pre-fetch them ahead of time before they need to be displayed. For example, if your App has a loading sequence before the page renders, you should delay that loading sequence longer to wait for that image to download. Then, once you're ready to display it, it will load/display instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you have 2 nested requests

**Second** you load the images like this in a while loop

```
discoverPostersData.append(try! Data(contentsOf: posterURL))
```

which is not a good way as it blocks the main thread , you have to load them asynchronously in a back ground queue

**Third** the completion of `URLSession.shared.dataTask` runs in background queue , so you need to use when setting the images to the UIImageViews

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

  // to set the images 
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your help ! You've solved my problem.